# Table td display block not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, doctype

I have a table, and I want make td to display block, it's ok on firefox and etc.. but not working on Chrome, I guess probably it's up to user agent stylesheet, even I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` before html tag but still not working, even important, it's look like override but actually it's read user agent stylesheet

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in my page there is no more CSS and I didn't use bootstrap.  any solution? i searched but all say it's `<!DOCTYPE html>` issue!

[image]

Comment: put your css code too.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal updated

Comment: please post your  completed html and css code as like  what is your  class in css and your html structure

Comment: `th,td{display:block;}` would help?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal no it's didn't help.

Comment: @RohitAzad how can I do this? I mean where I put my codes? anywhere?

Comment: @jiff can you create a fiddle and show me the problum i thing now your can try to this way  -->#Table tr td{display:table-row;}

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` worked in my case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table should be `display: table`. If you're worried about the lining, try adding `display:block` to the child elements.

The reason is that `display: table` creates the **table** **layout mechanism** , hence the rows and columns will be laid out properly;

In certain conditions if the required elements aren't there, they will be implicitly created, but it can cause problems. (You can test that out by making a table layout with divs and setting them to `display: table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, which are the default user agent styles for **table**, **tr**, and **td** elements. If you play around with unsetting the styles on the divs in different combinations, you'll see that sometimes the browser implicitly makes the table layout incorrectly.)

So, always leave the `display: table-* styles` intact if you want an actual table layout. Sort out your lining issues using the appropriate styles for that.

You can try **spaning across** several **divs**, and defining your child element in it, using `colspan`(on the `td`) and `display:block` (on the child-element).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in responsive after the last Chrome update 45.0.2454.85. The stacked table cells would render as a hybrid of table-cell and table-row after resizing the browser at responsive breakpoints (media queries), or when switching from portrait to landscape and back, if landscape didn't stack the table cells and portrait did. This bug occurs only when there are more than two table cells.

The solution: In the containing table row `tr` set it to display:table-cell.

```
table.classname tr { display:table-cell !important; }
table.classname td { display:block; width:100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
**`float: left;`**

Does not impact IE/FF where **`display: block`** works